# BASH how to wait for mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to complete

Tags: bash, load-data-infile

I have the following command in a BASH script. How can I check whether the command has completed uploading the file?

```
$(mysql -h "${1}" --user="${2}" --password="${3}" -D"${4}"   --skip-column-names --local-infile=1 -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tempFile' INTO TABLE $tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' " )
```

Comment: The script will not move on to the next command until this command has finished executing.

Comment: You don't need (or want) command substitution if you just want to run a command. Drop the `$(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the query and then check the status by looking at `$?`:

```
mysql -h "${1}" --user="${2}" --password="${3}" -D"${4}"   --skip-column-names --local-infile=1 -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tempFile' INTO TABLE $tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' "
if [ $? ... ]; then do_something
```

Comment: You seldom need to inspect `$?`.  Just `if ! mysql ...; then`.